# A replacement between lists

Tags: python

```
a = ["I like apple","I love you so much"]
```

I want to change "apple" and "love" words with followings : "orange","like"
but I don't want to change the elements ( sentences) in a so output must be

```
a= ["I like orange","I like you so much"]
```

No changes should happen in anything except words `orange` and `like`. Not even a space added or dropped.

Comment: Use `str.replace`: `a = [s.replace('apple', 'orange').replace('love', 'like') for s in a]`

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dictionary to do the mapping:

```
word_mapping = {
    'apple': 'orange',
    'love': 'like'
}
```

And then, providing you have a `list of strings`:

```
 def translate(text):
     return reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, word_mapping[y]), word_mapping, text)

 def translate_all(text_list):
      return [translate(s) for s in text_list]
```

e.g.:

```
a = ["I like apple","I love you so much"]
b = translate_all(a)
print(b)
# > ['I like orange', 'I like you so much']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
a[0].replace('apple', 'orange')
a[1].replace('love', 'like')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remain as it is try this,

```
>>> a = ["I like apple","I love you so much"]
>>> [i.replace('apple','orange').replace('love','like') for i in a]
['I like orange', 'I like you so much']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
What the following code does is loop the strings in the list and check for `apple` or the word `love` and replace them with `orange` or `like` accordingly and return the list back to you.

```
[(i.replace("apple","orange") or i.replace("love","like")) for i in a]
```

Here's an execution

```
>>> a = ["I like apple","I love you so much"]
>>> [(i.replace("apple","orange") or i.replace("love","like")) for i in a]
['I like orange', 'I love you so much']
```

Comment: it wont work.. 
>>> [i.replace('apple','orange') or replace('love','like') for i in a]
['I like orange', 'I love you so much']

priority matters

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Please check the update, I've added the sample execution. This seems to be in order with what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python, i.e cannot be modified
So, a call like

```
a[0].replace("apple","orange")
```

will return a new string and not change the original element of the list.

```
a[0]=a[0].replace("apple","orange")
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace_map = [
    ('apple', 'orange'),
    ('love', 'like')
]

def replace_all(s, m):
  for k, v in m:
    s = s.replace(k, v)
  return s

b = [replace_all(s, replace_map) for s in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension use, as proposed by Patrick Haugh, Sudheesh Singanamalla and Mohideen ibn Mohammed, is may be the more pythonic way ... 
Step by step and less pythonic is:

```
>>> a = ["I like apple","I love you so much"]
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)):
...     if a[i].find('apple') is not -1:
...             a[i]=a[i].replace('apple','orange')
...     if a[i].find('love') is not -1:
...             a[i]=a[i].replace('love','like')
... 
>>> a
['I like orange', 'I like you so much']
```

Or more directly:

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)):
...     a[i]=a[i].replace('apple','orange')
...     a[i]=a[i].replace('love','like')
... 
>>> a
['I like orange', 'I like you so much']
```